# Problems linking NSTableView handler class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a strange problem in my Cocoa-app. I have a main window with an **NSTableView** in it with a controller class (**PropValTableHandler**). I have made the connections between my NSTableView and the PropValTableHandler, but when the 'numberOfRowsInTableView' method is called it looks like not the 'PropValTableHandler' initialized in 'AddDelegate' is used, since the 'propMan' field is not initialized (it is like the normal init is used, so it has to be another instance of this class).
Am I doing something wrong? I have another NSTableView handler in another window, that works, but it does not have a custom init method.

Source codes:

**AppDelegate**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize propValTableController = _propValTableController;

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _propMan = [[OCPropertyManager alloc]initWithPath:"./data/"];
        _propValTableController = [[PropValTableHandler alloc] 
                                   [initWithPropManager:_propMan];
    }

    return self;
}
```

**PropValTableHandler**

```
@interface PropValTableHandler : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource>

@property IBOutlet NSTableView * constants;
@property OCPropertyManager    * propMan;

-(id) initWithPropManager:(OCPropertyManager*)pm;

-(NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;

@end


#import "PropValTableHandler.h"

@implementation PropValTableHandler


-(id) initWithPropManager:(OCPropertyManager*)pm
{
    self = [super self];
    if (self)
    {
        self.propMan = pm;
    }

    return self;
}

/*********** TABLEVIEW DATASOURCE ******************/
-(NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger count = [_propMan.consts count];
    return count;
}
/**************************************************/

@end
```

Comment: Could you post code where you initializing `_propMan`?

Comment: It is initialized in the 'initWithPropManager' method of PropValTableHandler

Comment: Now that I look at it again, do i need the "synthetize" for the '_propMan' field?

Comment: I'm not sure :). I can't get your problem

Comment: I have printed out the address of the PropValTableHandler's self at 'initWithPropManager': 0x0000608000430fa0 and in 'numberOfRowsInTableView': 0x000060800022a7c0. So it is clear that these are two different instances and i don't know why it is automatically initializing another one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding a

```
@property IBOutlet AppDelegate *parent;
```

for the PropValTableHandler class and making the connections.
This way I can use:

```
parent.propMan
```

where ever I need it without passing a reference to it in the init method.